# haskell function not working, can anyone tell me why?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to tell the user if a given number is even or odd, but it doen't seem to work...

```
typeOfInt :: Int -> String

typeOfInt integerValue
  |integerValue `mod` 2 == 0 = "even number"
  |otherwise = "odd number"

typeOfInt 27
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: Guessing: the test `typeOfInt 27` must not be written inside the .hs file, but is an expression to be evaluated inside GHCi.

Comment: Thank you!!! Now I know.

Comment: Just a note, in future it's helpful to include the error message you receive.

Answer (score 7):

The code itself it's ok and works, but it looks like you tried to evaluate the function in a Pythonic way, not exactly how you should use the functions in Haskell. You have to options here:

1. **Using the REPL**, by running `ghci` in the directory and then loading the file inside it (using the command `:l <filename>.hs`). Once in there, you can use the function interactively, by calling it like you are doing inside the file (`typeOfInt 27`) or with other functions (`map typeOfInt [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`).
2. **Creating a main method and compiling the file**. The main method in Haskell has to be a `main :: IO ()` method, and that is what will be executed once you run a compiled file.

For your example, you can use `putStrLn` to get the results that you seem to be looking for:

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ typeOfInt 27
```

As you can see, in this case it is arguably more useful to use the `ghci` and play with the functions instead of compiling.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful !